# Is it harmful to let cat groom synthetic fur toy?

Tags: cats, safety

I recently bought a key ring that has a long furry tail, presumably some kind of synthetic fur.  My cat loves to groom it, but I'm worried he may get a hairball from licking it, and that might be more harmful or toxic than a natural hairball he might get from grooming his own fur.  Should I forbid him from licking it?

Comment: What is the long furry tail made of? Fake fur? Anything else?